Dual Portable Monitor not working correctly
My Problem
I connect a dual screen monitor to my notebook. The notebook’s built-in screen works. The lower screen works. The upper screen does not get a signal.
The Windows Way
This is the same behavior as I perceive when connecting the monitor to a Windows system (same notebook). The monitor provides a USB device that contains drivers for Windows and MacOS. After installing the Windows Drive, the upper screen works. No Linux driver is provided by the manufacturer.
Your Help
Does anyone has an idea how I could make my Ubuntu system recognize the upper screen of the dual portable monitor?
Thanks for your time!
System information

Screen: EVICIV Portable Monitor 15.6'' Dual

System: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

Notebook: Lenovo ThinkPad X13

Setup: USB C Cable between notebook and Monitor. As I used the same setup in Windows before, I am sure power supply is sufficient and cable / port usage is correct.

xrandr
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 290mm x 170mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   *1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      60.03  
   1280x800      59.99  
   1152x720      59.97  
   960x600       59.96  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77*  
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 350mm x 200mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x720      59.97  
   960x600       59.63  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  


lspci
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 02)

$ lspci | grep USB
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
2b:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 USB 3.1 Controller (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)



I read that I can check whether Display Link driver would help. However, this returned no output:
$ lsusb -d 17e9:


Ubuntu drivers
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
All the available drivers are already installed.




It looks like you answered your own question. If a special driver is needed in one OS, in this case Windows. It makes sense that the same would be required in another OS. If the maker of the driver does not have one that works with Ubuntu I would have to say you are out of luck. You cold try writing to the make of the driver and ask them what would be a good fix.

Thank you for looking into this, @DavidDE! I was hoping for some crazy workaround someone with more technical knowledge than myself would have for me :-).

Shall I  make this an answer?
